# How can we detect and apply Lightning Experience defined Themes and Branding css styling in Lightning Application?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, slds, theme-branding

I'm looking to build a custom `Lightning Application` (*not* a `Lightning Component`). Now, SLDS base component does work nice, I've noticed that `Themes & Branding` applied theme color do not gets affected in the app.

So, if I place a button like this:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
     <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" />
</aura:application>
```

The button is rendered in the default SLDS styled colors in `Lightning Application` (code above):

[image]

```
<aura:component >
     <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" />
</aura:component>
```

While if I use same button code in a `Lightning Component` (code above):

[image]

Comment: where are you hosting that application? 

As component is hosted in one.app container it recives the theme css from the parent one.app

Comment: Well, it's a lightning application, I don't think we can host it inside one.app, it is it's own app :), thus wanted to know, if there is any way to determine Lightning Experience Theme branding?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal as it takes an API call to retrieve, but you can use the User Interface API to retrieve the active theme from your apex controller.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_themes_active.htm

Make a GET request to `/ui-api/themes/active` and you should retrieve a response with brandColor, brandImage, defaultGroupBanner, defaultGroupImage, defaultPageBanner, defaultUserBanner, defaultUserImage, headerColor, linkColor, and pageColor attributes. You can than use these to style your app.

Comment: Can we retrieve Active Theme from`Lightning Component` without UI API call? If so I can retrieve and possibly pass the theme in `Lightning Application` url parameters.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to retrieve the active theme yet, but since themes and brands were new in Spring '18 I wouldn't be surprised if they added a way to access it eventually.